Asian movie about a guy recording sounds and sending them to his girlfriend
About 2 years ago on some film festival I saw an Asian movie and I would really like to buy it somewhere or at least watch it again.
It is a movie about a sound recording guy that gets sacked, and has troubles with his girlfriend. I know he was traveling during the movie, so it was kind of an Asian road movie. While traveling he records tapes of anything he passes, birds, the sea, the woods, ...
I knew he sent them over to his girlfriends house.
I also knew that someone else heard those tapes and tried to traceback the steps the main character took, and tries to visit the places he went, ...
I know there was at least one other different story tangled into this but I forgot that one.
